# Model Import error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm getting the following error when trying to import models into my google app engine app:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/app/0-1.405524594589080344/main.py", line 6, in <module>
from BaseHandler import BaseHandler
  File "/base/data/home/apps/app/0-1.405524594589080344/BaseHandler.py", line 26, in <module>
from user.database import u_db
  File "/base/data/home/apps/app/0-1.405524594589080344/user/database/u_db.py", line 12, in <module>
from clubs.database import fed_db, league_db, club_db
  File "/base/data/home/apps/app/0-1.405524594589080344/clubs/database/fed_db.py", line 6, in <module>
from events.database import e_db
  File "/base/data/home/apps/app/0-1.405524594589080344/events/database/e_db.py", line 7, in <module>
from user.database import u_db
ImportError: cannot import name u_db
```

I renamed the model files and their container folders, and can see this has something to do with Path.

I would really appreciate some help in fixing this as I am stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there \_\_init__.py files in user and database folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular dependency in your models, see these snippets in your traceback:

```
  File "/base/data/home/apps/app/0-1.405524594589080344/BaseHandler.py", line 26, in <module>
from user.database import u_db

...

  File "/base/data/home/apps/app/0-1.405524594589080344/events/database/e_db.py", line 7, in <module>
from user.database import u_db
```

You need to fix that. Often it can be done simply by moving the import statements inside the functions where they are actually needed instead of just at the top of the file. But not always.